# Convert Labview to Source listing

Tags: labview

We use Labview to create test software used in electronic circuit boards and electronic box testing.  The Technicians that use the code need access to an uneditable version of the software in order to know what the failing test were trying to do.  Creating a document to describe every thing each individual test is doing would be a costly long process using the Labview code from a large project.

Is there a way to convert the Labview source code into a text version of code such as (C, C+, C#, XML or Python...) that then could be saved as a PDF and distributed with the test software.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You can print a LabVIEW VI's block diagram, to a PDF if you have a PDF writer, but that doesn't capture options or properties that you would access from right-click menus, and isn't easy to follow if you have case structures.

If you want to allow technicians to browse LabVIEW code without changing it, you can use straightforward methods like OS permissions (giving them read-only access to it). LabVIEW is used in many regulated environments such as medical device testing where it's essential to be able to verify that the correct version of software was used to perform a test, so if you need more information on this sort of thing you'll be able to find plenty of help from NI or on the NI site.

It sounds as if your real problem may be that your test code is not very well designed or organised. Perhaps you should look at refactoring it to be more modular, so that it's easier to understand and document what test a particular module is performing. You might want to look at the OOP capabilities in LabVIEW, or a framework such as the Delacor queued message handler - or even something like TestStand.